# Jessie in Kiosk mode on the Pi Zero, the proper way

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, jessie-lite, kiosk

I have looked far and wide, and also read a lot of the (mostly marked duplicate) questions already posted here. But I can't seem to find a conclusive answer for my situation.

I want to run a browser window in kiosk mode on a **Pi Zero**, running Raspbian Jessie **lite**.

It came to my attention that Chromium is no longer supplied as a package in Jessie, and that the hacky workaround is only for the pi 2 and 3.

Furthermore, most people don't bother with the lite version and run a full desktop underneath.

I'm looking for the least "hacky" approach to this, since I want it to run stable yet perform.

Comment: If 'performant' is one of your criteria you may have picked the wrong Pi. I've read some good things about kweb and epiphany in the past, might be worth a look.

Comment: you should read that as "as performant as it can be" aka optimized.

Comment: I thought Jessie-Lite didn't have a desktop environment.

Comment: you can just install one afterwards, or just a window manager alone

Answer (score 1):

jessie-lite does not come with a graphical server, and therefore you will not be able to run a graphical application such as a web browser.

The *least "hacky" approach* is to install jessie (full), and then configure a kiosk mode for a browser of your choice.

Comment: just because it doesn't ship with one doesn't mean you can't install one later. You should always be able to install a window-manager etc.

Comment: You asked for the least "hacky" approach.

Answer (score 1):

It appears now that the Chromium browser is available. `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser rpi-chromium-mods`.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with Stretch (latest) light and then install the desktop of your choice which will drag in X and friends.  Alternative desktops to LXDE are XFCE and Mate.

Answer (score 0):

Jessie lite is designed as a headless OS so without a "hacky" approach it doesn't look like you can install chrome or another browser. I am running a pi zero W that is doing the exact same thing and running Raspbian Stretch which has chrome pre-installed and it works perfectly. Good luck with your project.